# ant: running phpcb after phpunit fails

Tags: php, ant, build, phpunit

In the recommended ant script for php, phpcb is given at the end since it uses all log files made by phpcs, phpmd, phpunit, phpcpd etc. The issue is my phpunit is not passing these days and phpcb wont run without all previous processes are returning true and the build fails without phpcb. So how to make phpcb run after all tools regardless of exit code?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the PHPUnit tests.

If impossible, skip those tests that are failing, with a call to `$this->markTestSkipped('Here is the reason why this test isn't fixed...')`.

See the [documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests) for more details.

If you run PHPUnit in verbose mode, you'll get a constant reminder to fix the tests.

Answer (score 0):

In build.xml you can ignore phpunit failure and continue with the execution of Ant script.

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="false">
    [...]
</target>
```